# WorkManager chaining when the work graph isn't known upfront

Tags: android, android-workmanager

In my application I have a workflow like this:

1. Ask server for instruction
2. Perform a variable number of jobs (ideally in parallel, order is unimportant) according to the server's response in step 1
3. Tell server "I'm done!" once all jobs from 2 are done

With WorkManager, if I want to chain work together, I need to be able to specify the work graph up front. However, I don't know how many parallel work requests to add for step 2 until I have the server response from step 1.

What's the best way to go about this?

Of course, in the worker for step 1, I can just create a chain once I have the response and enqueue that, but this seems less than ideal.

I have considered creating only one work request for step 2 and having the worker iteratively do the work needed. However, this is not an acceptable solution because of the 10-minute execution limit which is liable to be exceeded. It would also result in non-ideal behaviour if this work request had to be retried.

Comment: Don't you have to create all of the Workers for step 2 in the Worker of Step 1 (where you have the response) anyways? At that point, you have all the information you need for Step 2 and 3 and no prerequisites, which is everything you need. Am I missing something?

Comment: What I would ideally like is some sort of hierarchical worker, i.e. a worker that can be put in a simple linear chain, but instead of performing the work itself it dispatches to a series of sub-tasks as it decides to, and then performs a collection operation on the result and passes it down the chain. I understand I could DIY this with ListenableWorker but then surely this would result in the 10 minute limit being applied meaning all sub tasks would have to finish within 10 mins of the parent task starting (which might not happen e.g. due to constraints). Basically, MapReduce.

Comment: That's exactly what [chained work](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/chain-work) gives you already when using `ArrayCreatingInputMerger`. Is there a particular reason you don't want to use the tools already provided? They seem to fit exactly the case you are describing

Comment: I suppose ultimately it can be done using chained work as-is, but: 

1. It would be nice to be able to treat a particular chain of subtasks as a single logical "super" task that can itself be chained and reused
2. It would be nice to be able to build a chain containing one of these super tasks and have it figure out what subtasks need to run when it comes time to execute it, rather than needing to know this upfront (or else create a totally new chain)